# protasis use of should and shall

Tags: modal-verbs, conditional-constructions

> There is also an archaic use of shall in an open protasis, still found in some legal language: *If the tenant shall at any time fail to keep the demised premises as aforesaid the landlord may do all things necessary to effect or maintain such insurance*. *Shall fail* here is semantically indistinguishable from *fails*; this use of *shall* is comparable to that of *should* in [28iv].
> (The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language, p195)

Even though the book says the use of shall in the example is comparable to that of should in [28iv] below, I suspect there might be a typo: [28iv] for [28v]. For the example and [28v] have a similarity in that they get protases. Is it a typo or is there anything for me to know better?

> [28iv] It’s surprising that he should have been so late. [emotive]
>   [28v] If you should experience any difficulty, please let me know. [conditional]

Comment: I think you nailed it: it's v, not iv.

Comment: @StoneyB, No, they seem to say the example’s and [28iv]’s shall and should respectively can be unmodalised. (“The should clause can generally be replaced by an unmmodlaised one: compare [28iv] with ‘It’s surprising that he was so late.’ p.188)

Comment: But so can [28v]: *If you experience any difficulty ...*. And as you point out, [28v] is a conditional, [28iv] is not.  *If the tenant shall fail* can equally be replaced by *If the tenant should fail*, which is "comparable", but *that he should have been so late* cannot be replaced by *that he *shall have been so late*. I betcha HuddlePuddle added a paragraph at some point and got their sequence muddled.

Comment: I now feel like I should really see a few more paragraphs before and after that quote. Then, I might have a better idea on author's real intention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, I'm not sure that this is a typo; however, at the same time, *should* and *shall* are not interchangeable in [28iv]. ***Comparable*** and ***interchangeable*** are not quite the same. They're basically saying that it is being used **exactly the same** as it is in [28iv].

This has nothing to do with conditionals. It's more a question of semantics. Yes, the text in the paragraph and [28v] are both conditionals (as indicated by *if/shall/should* and *may*), whereas [28iv] is not; but, that's not what they're talking about.

In example [28iv], *that he should be so late,* is semantically the same as *that he was so late*, just as *if the tenant shall fail to* is the same as saying *if the tenant fails to*. There is no change in meaning by removing either *should* or *shall*.

And while example [28iv] doesn't work with *shall*, it's **used in the exact same way**, meaning that *shall* is being used in that paragraph in the **same way** that *should* is being used in [28iv]. The modal adds absolutely nothing to the meaning. But, at the same time, you can't say *it's surprising that he **shall** have been so late*, at least not in Modern English.

That is **not** the point that the book is trying to make though. They simply mean they're the same usage, not that they're interchangeable. Here's the relevant context: ***Shall fail here is semantically indistinguishable from fails***; this use of shall is **comparable to that of should in [28iv].**

In other words, *that he should be* is ***indistinguishable*** from *was*. That's a very literal reading of the text. So strictly speaking, it's correct.

On the other hand, with example [28v], *If you should experience any difficultly, please contact me*, *should* also has little meaning. *If*, though, is completely unnecessary in that sentence. It could be re-written as *Should you experience any difficulty, please let me know.* Saying *if you should experience*, is more like saying *If you **happen to** experience any problems, please let me know.* Think of *if you should* as being similar to *in case* here.

While I'm sure that there are plenty of speakers who wouldn't think twice of omitting *should* from [28v], it's not technically correct to do so. Although it probably wouldn't change the meaning of the sentence to most speakers if *should* were omitted, you're asking about a reference book, so it's most likely following prescriptive rules of grammar.

And even if that weren't the case, *should* adds politeness and formality to the sentence. That's not the case with [28iv].

What I take issue with, however, is that example [28iv] is the one using archaic language (in the US at least). But it's **not the same** as the archaic American use of *shall* that is only found in legal documents, which is what they're trying to explain.

This is very poorly explained in my opinion.

Comment: No, CGEL is not a prescriptive reference.  It describes Standard English.

Comment: @snailboat that's fine; does that make the rest of what I wrote incorrect? It's not a book I often need, so I may have made an incorrect assumption; but I think I'm the only one (other than you perhaps) that understood why it may not be a typo. By the way, isn't the concept of Standard English itself prescriptive?

Comment: No.  Prescriptivism is advice; this covers a different range of topics than a description of Standard English.  There's no reason a prescriptive reference can't agree with a descriptive one on the points where they do overlap, but for some reason it seldom works out this way in practice.